# Issues in TabFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have set `13 tab fragment(Category)` by using of `ViewPager` in my app. I'm having lot of issue in this `TabFragment`. I tried to fix this bug in many ways.But nothing works in my case. So please help me to fix this.

Issues are:

1. 1st Fragment is populated with 2nd Fragment (Category) Data.
2. I am having 3 vertical Dots of **...** , When I press the next fragment data is replaced. (See the picture that I attached).
3. 3rd Issue is [Data Loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661183/how-to-stop-reloading-of-a-tab-fragment-while-swiping/36661311#36661311) here.

[image]  ............... [image]

My Codes are Here:

Adapter Class:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    public static String CART_COUNT;
    public static String CART_TOTAL;
    public static int countCART;
    public static int TotalCART;
    //    static List<Restaurant_Beam> restaurant_prducts;
    static List<CartRes> RestaurantList;

    Config config;
    ArrayList<String> CATEGORYNAME = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ITEMNAME = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> ITEM_PRICE = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> LIKE_COUNT = new ArrayList<>();

    int clickedPos = -1;

    String CART_PRODUCT_ID,
            CART_PRICE,
            CART_PDT_NAME,
            CART_QUANTITY,
            CART_CAT_ID,
            CART_STATUS,
            CART_CATEGORY;

    CommonUtil commonUtil;
    byte[] product_pic;
    CartRes Restaurant = new CartRes();
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(List<CartRes> cartRestaurant, Context context) {
        super();
        this.RestaurantList = cartRestaurant;
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println("Filter Result" + cartRestaurant);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_list_item_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        commonUtil.dbUtil = new DbUtil(context);
        commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        commonUtil.pref = context.getSharedPreferences(CommonUtil.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        commonUtil.dbUtil = new DbUtil(context);
        commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
        System.out.println("Filter Result" + "........1");
        Restaurant = RestaurantList.get(position);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto.medium.ttf");
        Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto.regular.ttf");

        config.IMAGE_URL = "http://ec2-54-251-155-163.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/product_images/devdemopos1.jpg";

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(config.IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.productImage, 0, 0)); 
//config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getIG_IMAGEURL()
//        String IMAGE_URL = config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getIG_IMAGEURL();
        String IMAGE_URL = config.IMAGE_URL;
        String ITEM_NAME = Restaurant.JSON_PRODUCT_NAME;
        String CATEGORY_NAME = Restaurant.JSON_CATEGORY_NAME;
        int CAT_ID = Restaurant.JSON_CATEGORY_ID;
        String PRICE = String.valueOf(Restaurant.JSON_SALES_PRICE);
        int LIKECOUNT = (Restaurant.JSON_LIKECOUNT);
        int DeliveryTime = Integer.parseInt((Restaurant.JSON_DELIVERY_TIME));
        int COMMENTCOUNT = 200;
        String VOUCHER_ID = Restaurant.JSON_VOUCHER_ID;
        String ITEMID = String.valueOf(Restaurant.JSON_PRODUCT_ID);
        final String PICTUREID = Restaurant.JSON_IMAGE_ID;

        holder.productImage.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
        holder.txt_itemName.setText(ITEM_NAME);
        holder.txt_itemName.setTypeface(tf);

        holder.txt_categoryName.setText(CATEGORY_NAME);
        holder.txt_itemName.setTypeface(tf1);
        holder.txt_Price.setText(PRICE);

        holder.txtFav.setText(String.valueOf(LIKECOUNT));
        holder.txtItemID.setText(ITEMID);
        holder.comment_count.setText(String.valueOf(COMMENTCOUNT));
        holder.txtTime.setText(String.valueOf(DeliveryTime));
        holder.txtCategoryID.setText(String.valueOf(CAT_ID));

        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ITEMNAME.add(ITEM_NAME);
        CATEGORYNAME.add(CATEGORY_NAME);
        ITEM_PRICE.add(PRICE);
        LIKE_COUNT.add(String.valueOf(LIKECOUNT));


        holder.productImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Config.adapterClicked = true;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = commonUtil.pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("FRAGMENT", Config.adapterClicked);
                editor.commit();

                holder.productImage.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = holder.productImage.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                product_pic = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("itemName", holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("categoryName", holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("Price", Double.parseDouble(holder.txt_Price.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("like", Integer.parseInt(holder.txtFav.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("itemID", holder.txtItemID.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("CATID", holder.txtCategoryID.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("picture", product_pic);
                i.putExtra("pictureId", PICTUREID);
                i.putExtra("comment", Integer.parseInt(holder.comment_count.getText().toString()));
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        if (clickedPos == position) {
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.txt_categoryName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txt_itemName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iv_settings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.iv_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickedPos = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        holder.viewDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Config.adapterClicked = true;
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = commonUtil.pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("FRAGMENT", Config.adapterClicked);
                editor.commit();

                holder.productImage.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = holder.productImage.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                product_pic = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("itemName", holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("categoryName", holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("Price", Double.parseDouble(holder.txt_Price.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("like", Integer.parseInt(holder.txtFav.getText().toString()));
                i.putExtra("itemID", holder.txtItemID.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("CATID", holder.txtCategoryID.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("picture", product_pic);
                i.putExtra("pictureId", PICTUREID);
                i.putExtra("comment", Integer.parseInt(holder.comment_count.getText().toString()));

                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }

        });
        holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                commonUtil.dbUtil.open();

                CART_PDT_NAME = holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString();
                CART_CATEGORY = holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString();
                CART_PRICE = holder.txt_Price.getText().toString();
                Integer.parseInt(holder.txtFav.getText().toString());
                CART_PRODUCT_ID = holder.txtItemID.getText().toString();
                CART_CAT_ID = holder.txtCategoryID.getText().toString();
                Integer.parseInt(holder.comment_count.getText().toString());

                holder.productImage.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = holder.productImage.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                product_pic = stream.toByteArray();
                hadInBasket();
            }

            private void hadInBasket() {
                Cursor CHECK = commonUtil.dbUtil.isInCart(CART_PRODUCT_ID);
                if (CHECK != null && CHECK.moveToFirst()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Already added into the cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    addtocart();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Added into Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            private void addtocart() {
                if (MainActivity.mCounter != null) {
                    countCART++;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = commonUtil.pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("cartCount", String.valueOf(countCART));
                    editor.commit();
                    CART_COUNT = commonUtil.pref.getString("cartCount", "00");
                    CART_TOTAL = commonUtil.pref.getString("cartTotal", "00");
                    MainActivity.mCounter.setText(CART_COUNT);
                }
                CART_QUANTITY = "1";
                commonUtil.dbUtil.addtocart(CART_PRODUCT_ID, CART_PDT_NAME, CART_PRICE, CART_QUANTITY, CART_CATEGORY, CART_CAT_ID, CommonUtil.CART_PDT_STATUS, CART_TOTAL, product_pic);
            }
        });
        holder.checkOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CART_PDT_NAME = holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString();
                CART_CATEGORY = holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString();
                CART_PRICE = holder.txt_Price.getText().toString();
                Integer.parseInt(holder.txtFav.getText().toString());
                CART_PRODUCT_ID = holder.txtItemID.getText().toString();
                CART_CAT_ID = holder.txtCategoryID.getText().toString();

                holder.productImage.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = holder.productImage.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                product_pic = stream.toByteArray();

                IsItInWishList();
            }

            private void IsItInWishList() {
                Cursor CHECK = commonUtil.dbUtil.isInWishList(CART_PRODUCT_ID);
                if (CHECK != null && CHECK.moveToFirst()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Already in  the wishlist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    int priceInt = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(CART_PRICE));
                    commonUtil.dbUtil.addTowish(CART_PRODUCT_ID, CART_PDT_NAME, CART_CATEGORY, priceInt, product_pic);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Added into WishList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return RestaurantList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView productImage;
        public TextView txt_categoryName, txtFav, txtItemID, txtCategoryID;
        public TextView txt_itemName, txt_Price, comment_count, txtTime;
        public CardView cardlist_item;
        public ImageView iv_settings;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public Button viewDetail, addToCart, checkOut;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_settings = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_settings);
            cardlist_item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_item);
            txt_itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_itemName);
            txt_Price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Price);
            txt_categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoryName);
            productImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
            txtFav = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtFav);
            txtItemID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemID);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearTransparent);
            viewDetail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butViewDetail);
            addToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.but_addTCart);
            checkOut = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butCheckOut);
            comment_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_count);
            txtTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTime);
            txtCategoryID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_id_hidden);
        }
    }
}
```

TabFragment.class:

```
public class TabFragmentSearch extends Fragment {
    public static int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    public static boolean loading = true;
    public static SearchView edtSearch;

    GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    Context context;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    boolean swipeCheck;
    Config config;
    TextView noData;
    CommonUtil commonUtil;
    List<CartRes> cartRestaurant;
    private List<CartRes> RestaurantDataSet;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public static TabFragmentSearch newInstance(int categoryId, String categoryName) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
        args.putString(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_NAME, categoryName);

        TabFragmentSearch fragment = new TabFragmentSearch();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        config = new Config(getActivity());
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); //SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN


        CommonUtil.pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(CommonUtil.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        config = new Config(getActivity());
        context = getActivity();
        CommonUtil.pref = context.getSharedPreferences(CommonUtil.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        commonUtil.dbUtil = new DbUtil(context);
        commonUtil.dbUtil.open();
        commonUtil.dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_rv);
        edtSearch = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.edtSearch);
        noData = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.noData);
        noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RestaurantDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

        swipeCheck = false;

        cartRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
        RestaurantDataSet = MainActivity.cartRestaurant;

        int BeanCatId = getArguments().getInt(CommonUtil.CATEGORY_ID);

        Config.startFilterClicked = false;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = CommonUtil.pref.edit();
        editor1.putBoolean("startFilter", Config.startFilterClicked);
        editor1.commit();


        Cursor curCAT_PDT = commonUtil.dbUtil.getCAT_PDT(String.valueOf(BeanCatId));

        if (curCAT_PDT != null && curCAT_PDT.moveToFirst()) {
            curCAT_PDT.moveToFirst();
            while (curCAT_PDT.isAfterLast() == false) {

                cartRestaurant.add(new CartRes(curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_ID)), curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_NAME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_PRODUCT_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_PRODUCT_NAME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_SALES_PRICE)), curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_IMAGE_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_SHOP_ID)), curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_DELIVERY_TIME)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getInt(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_LIKECOUNT)), curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_VOUCHER_ID)),
                        curCAT_PDT.getString(curCAT_PDT.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.JSON_VOUCHER_OFFER))));


                curCAT_PDT.moveToNext();
            }
            adapter = new CardAdapter(cartRestaurant, context);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                if (dy > 0) {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                    if (loading) {
                        if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                            loading = false;
                            Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        edtSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + " query" + query);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, query);
                if (filteredModelList.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No Search Data Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                System.out.println("TabFragment Search" + "newText " + newText);
                final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = filter(RestaurantDataSet, newText);

                adapter = new CardAdapter(filteredModelList, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                return true;
            }
        });

        edtSearch.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                edtSearch.clearFocus();

                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                return false;
            }
        });
        noData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private List<CartRes> filter(List<CartRes> restaurantDataSet, String strSearch) {

        final List<CartRes> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CartRes restaurant : restaurantDataSet) {
            final String text = restaurant.JSON_PRODUCT_NAME.toLowerCase();
            if (text.contains(strSearch)) {
                filteredModelList.add(restaurant);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.badge).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

**Tab Instance getting data from MainActivity Tab ViewPagerAdapter:**

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return TabFragmentSearch.newInstance(jSonCatId.get(position), jSonTab.get(position));    //newInstance
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return jSonTab.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return jSonTab.get(position);
}
}
```

Comment: Try to set the each tab with different adapter class

Comment: But the Tab Count is  unknown.Depends on the category count, Tab  will increase. If  the count increase adapter class is also increased.Isn't it?

Comment: Then you use simple Base Adapter

Comment: Show your complete codefor better understanding your problem

Comment: I updated my code.Please check it.

Comment: Try to use simple adapter class instead of 'RecyclerViewAdapter' because RecyclerView Adapter  is automatically updated when you call thw second fragment.